# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user on MaxScale

Tags: database, mariadb, load-balancing, maxscale

I set up MaxScale so I tried to test whether it work or not.
I did tried to access from application server using this command below

`$ mysql --host=192.168.30.145 --user=client --password -P 3309`

and then, I got this error

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'client'@'::ffff:192.168.30.161' (using password: YES)
```

and this is an error messege in  /var/log/maxscale/maxscale.log

```
warning: (2) [MariaDBProtocol] Authentication failed for user 'client'@[::ffff:192.168.30.161] to service 'Write-Service'. Originating listener: 'Write-Listener'. MariaDB error: 'Access denied for user 'client'@'::ffff:192.168.30.161' (using password: YES)'.
```

Here is the information of the MaxScale and MariaDb I set up.

・masterDB:192.168.30.140

・replicaDB1:192.168.30.141

・replicaDB2:192.168.30.142

・replicaDB3:192.168.30.143

・maxscale:192.168.30.145

・application server:192.168.30.161

on masterDB, I made user account such as **maxscale@%**, **monitor@%**, and **client@192.168.30.145**
As for each replicaDB, I made **read@192.168.30.145**

For now, I did `Systemctl stop ufw` on all servers, and
changed `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` to `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` on all DB

```
[maxscale]
threads=auto

[MariaDB-Monitor]
type=monitor
module=mariadbmon
servers=masterDB, replicaDB1, replicaDB2, replicaDB3
user=monitor
password=alj123
monitor_interval=2s

[masterDB]
type=server
address=192.168.30.140
port=3306
protocol=MariaDBBackend

[replicaDB1]
type=server
address=192.168.30.141
port=3306
protocol=MariaDBBackend

[replicaDB2]
type=server
address=192.168.30.142
port=3306
protocol=MariaDBBackend

[replicaDB3]
type=server
address=192.168.30.143
port=3306
protocol=MariaDBBackend

[Write-Service]
type=service
router=readconnroute
router_options=master
servers=masterDB
user=maxscale
password=alj123

[Read-Service]
type=service
router=readconnroute
router_options=slave
servers=replicaDB1, replicaDB2, replicaDB3
user=read
password=alj123

[Write-Listener]
type=listener
service=Write-Service
protocol=MariaDBClient
port=3309

[Read-Listener]
type=listener
service=Read-Service
protocol=MariaDBClient
port=3310
```

```
users on masterDB
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for maxscale@%                                                                                                            |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT SHOW DATABASES, BINLOG MONITOR ON *.* TO `maxscale`@`%` IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*9639F24DBDAFA8F106318B335C271B581801E286' |
| GRANT SELECT ON `mysql`.`db` TO `maxscale`@`%`                                                                                   |
| GRANT SELECT ON `mysql`.`proxies_priv` TO `maxscale`@`%`                                                                         |
| GRANT SELECT ON `mysql`.`columns_priv` TO `maxscale`@`%`                                                                         |
| GRANT SELECT ON `mysql`.`roles_mapping` TO `maxscale`@`%`                                                                        |
| GRANT SELECT ON `mysql`.`user` TO `maxscale`@`%`                                                                                 |
| GRANT SELECT ON `mysql`.`tables_priv` TO `maxscale`@`%`                                                                          |
| GRANT SELECT ON `mysql`.`procs_priv` TO `maxscale`@`%`                                                                           |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for monitor@%                                                                                                           |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT RELOAD, SUPER, BINLOG MONITOR ON *.* TO `monitor`@`%` IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*9639F24DBDAFA8F106318B335C271B581801E286' |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for client@192.168.30.145                                                                                                            |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON *.* TO `client`@`192.168.30.145` IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*9639F24DBDAFA8F106318B335C271B581801E286' |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
user on each replicaDB
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for read@192.168.30.145                                                                                    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO `read`@`192.168.30.145` IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*9639F24DBDAFA8F106318B335C271B581801E286' |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
user on application sever
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for client@192.168.30.161                                                                                                            |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON *.* TO `client`@`192.168.30.161` IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*9639F24DBDAFA8F106318B335C271B581801E286' |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

・did `grant ALL PRIVILEGES` client@192.168.30.145, then I didn't get the error but I could INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE on replicaDB. I wanna allow client to do only SELECT on replicaDB

・changed client's host from 192.168.30.145 to %, then I didn't get the error but I don't wanna allow client to access DB from servers other than maxscale server(192.168.30.145)

Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: Access denied for user 'client'@'::ffff:`192.168.30.161`' - but you defined client@`192.168.30.145` ?!

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Georg.
I defined client@192.168.30.161 as a test client from application server and client@192.168.30.145 on masterDB to make client@192.168.30.161 connect to DB through MaxScale. I read document here "Creating a user account for MaxScale"
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-maxscale-6-setting-up-mariadb-maxscale/#creating-a-user-account-for-maxscale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it failed is because you defined the user with one specific IP address (`client@192.168.30.145`) and you need to define it twice (unless you use `proxy_protocol`): once for the client IP and another time for the MaxScale IP. This is mentioned in the [MaxScale Troubleshooting](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/maxscale-troubleshooting/#access-denied) article as well as [the MaxScale tutorial](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-maxscale-2302-setting-up-mariadb-maxscale/#creating-client-user-accounts).

Instead of defining the users twice or using a wildcard to match all IPs, the best way to solve this is to add the MaxScale IP to [proxy_protocol_networks](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#proxy_protocol_networks) in MariaDB and turn on [proxy_protocol](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-maxscale-2302-mariadb-maxscale-configuration-guide/#proxy_protocol) for all servers in MaxScale.

This makes MaxScale a trusted proxy for authentication that then allows MaxScale to relay the original IP to the MariaDB server to be used for the final authentication. This essentially makes MaxScale transparent to the whole authentication process which is what you usually want from a proxy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, markusjm.
I'd like to ask you about creating two user. I defined two 'client' this time. One of them on masterDB(client@maxscale's host), and another one on application server(client@client's host). You mean should have I defined both of them on masterDB?
Btw, I appreciate the information about proxy_protocol!  I will try it.

Comment: All the users need to be defined in the same database, otherwise you'll only get a partial set of users if they're read from there. I'd recommend going with proxy_protocol as it greatly simplifies user management with MaxScale.

Comment: I see. I appreciate your kindness. I just defined in the same database and it worked! Now as you said, I will use proxy_protocol. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi, markusjm. Could I ask you about setting proxy_protocol? Is it still necessary to define two users in DB while I'm using proxy_protocol? I put "proxy_protocol=true" in MaxScale and "proxy_protocol_networks = 192.168.30.145/24, localhost" in MariaDB. And then, I delete client@client-host from masterDB. Consequently, I got the same error again. I may misunderstand about using proxy_protocol.

Comment: You need to delete the `user@maxscale-ip` instead of `user@client-ip`.

Comment: I appreciate your help, markusjm.
I just deleted user@maxscale-ip and it worked!
In summary, do I need to set "proxy_protocol=true" in MaxScale , "proxy_protocol_networks = 192.168.30.145/24, localhost" in MariaDB, and create user@client-ip in primary DB to use MaxScale with a simple way?

Comment: Yes, that's the simplest and in my opinion the best way to manage users with MaxScale.

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much for all your help, markusjm.